# I have a three spinner,Fill these spinner to corresponding the other one..how can I fill

Tags: android, web-services, spinner

I have three Spinner,Location Route and customer.I fill it From Webservice.There is some Routes some locations and some customers,If I select Location then Corresponding of this location Route Should be come..and If I select the route then Corresponding the route Customers Should be come..How can I do This..PLease Help me..

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

override `setOnItemSelectedListener` and there

on location selection set the value in adapter and set this adapter to Routes and repeat this process for Routes to customers...